# 2 hours layover in Heathrow

Tags: layovers, lhr, british-airways

I am planning to book a British Airways flight from Bangalore to San Jose via London Heathrow on 12th August. The official  website shows a 2 hours 20 mins layover in Heathrow. **Both the flights are arriving and departing from T5.** Both the flights are British Airways flights. Planning to book it via the Official website. Given below are the flight details.

07:00 12 Aug Bengaluru ---13:05 12 Aug Heathrow (London)
British Airways
BLR-LHR
BA0118
Economy

15:25 12 Aug Heathrow (London) ---18:15 12 Aug San Jose (CA)
British Airways
LHR-SJC
BA0279
Economy

My queries

- Will the layover be an issue?
- Would I have to undergo any immigration checks?
- Would I have to pick up my checked luggage again and then re-check them?
- Will I get another flight to San Jose if I miss it due to any delay in arrival of the flight from Bangalore?

Comment: What kind of issues are you anticipating? Also what kind of visa do you have for USA? If it is not a sticker on your passport then you would need a transit visa for UK (assuming it is an Indian passport).

Comment: I am going to the US on a student visa which is valid for 5 years,

Comment: I've done two T5-T5 connecting flights a couple of weeks ago with 1 hour between them, and both went well, first flight was a 15 minutes affair, second flight was a 40 minutes affair (lot more walking because flight gate was not announced at the time of landing)

Comment: That is good.  Will update you guys after my experience. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your layover is normal, it is well above the minimum connect time of one hour.

There is no immigration control for international-to-international passengers (except those going to Ireland). (But you will pass through a security check.)

You will not need to collect your luggage, it will be checked through to San Jose.

BA will reroute you to San Jose if you miss your connection. There is only one flight per day to San Jose, so your options may include indirect flights on their partner American Airlines. You might also be able to take one of the BA flights to San Francisco, which is within driving distance of San Jose.

Comment: Thanks mate. Any idea which gate in Terminal 5 will i land in ?

Comment: @pacific Gates are not planned in advance, but normally longhaul services arrive at either the B pier or the C pier.